# Restart Computers and Send a Log

Tags: windows-7, batch, logging, reboot

I am in need of assistance. I'm trying to make a batch file to restart computers on my network and send a log of what computers successfully restarted and what computers were not. I know to restart the command is shutdown -r but I'm not sure how to get it to send a log file. A quick rundown I am trying to do is:

At (Time) warn user logged in that computer will restart in 30 minutes and to save their work before the restart.
At (Time) warn the user that the computer will restart in 5 minutes and to save their work before the restart.
At (Time) shutdown -r
Upon successful/unsuccessful restart send a log (Workstation was restarted successfully/unsuccessfully at *TIME*) to (Server/Folder)

If you need more information please let me know

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, shutdown (I use it) merely does what it asked of it and does not know if the computer restarted. You would need to query the computer after the restart.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please show whatever code you have already written.

Comment: I don't exactly have a code yet. All I know is how to restart the computer via Batch with shutdown -r.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to run from a server which does not shut down. It will send a message to all computers defined in the $Servers list that says "this computer will shutdown in 30 minutes. Then sleep for 30 mins, then send a restart command and write all the data to a logfile on how long it took them to come back up -- if they do.:

```
$Servers = "computer1", "computer2", "computer3"

$StartTime = Get-Date
$logFile = "C:\temp\log.txt"

Workflow Workflow-Restart
    {
        param (
            [DateTime]$StartTime,
            [string[]]$Servers
        )

foreach -parallel($server in $Servers) 
{
    $RestartTimer = "1800"  #30 minutes in seconds
    $Message1  = "Computer will be restarted in 30 minutes."

    #Send message #1
    MSG * /SERVER:$server /TIME:30 $Message1

    Start-Sleep -Seconds $RestartTimer

    Restart-Computer -PSComputerName $server -For PowerShell -Force -Wait
    $EndTime = Get-Date
    $minutes = (New-TimeSpan $StartTime $EndTime).Minutes
    $seconds = (New-TimeSpan $StartTime $EndTime).Seconds
    Write-Output "Time Taken for $server to come online: $minutes minutes : $seconds seconds" | Out-File $logFile -Append
    }
}

Workflow-Restart $StartTime $Servers
```

Comment: For the $Servers is there a way to use a list of computers? I have over 300 computers I need to restart weekly. Sorry if I'm causing any trouble.

Comment: I get an error that states '$Servers' is not a recognized internal or external command.